# Reading an updated input in a protractor test as a string

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to read an input for an operation in protractor. I'm trying to send an ajax request from within protractor. I need to send a unique value (which I'm calling `groupCode`) to a part of a JSON object that I want to send to the server.

So first I tried setting up a hidden input that could be updated. I have tried:

```
<div style='hidden' >
    <input 
        id="group-sendgrid-hidden-input" 
        ng-model='groupCode' 
        value='{{groupCode}}' 
        ng-init='groupCode=dangdangdang'
    >
</div>
```

Also this attempt to read the model value:

```
<div style='hidden' >
    <input 
        id="group-sendgrid-hidden-input" 
        ng-model='groupCode' 
        value='{{groupCode}}' 
        ng-init='groupCode=dangdangdang'
    >
   {{groupCode}}
</div>
```

Now, I can see in the Angular console that this value updates as I except. Meaning that `$scope.groupCode` does resolve to 'dangdangdang'. So I don't thing this is the issue. From here, I'm hoping to read the groupCode string in a protractor test as followed:

Here is some of what I've tried:

```
var groupCodeModel      = element(by.model('groupCode'));
var groupCodeBinding    = element(by.binding('groupCode'));
var placeholder         = groupCodeBinding.getText();
```

also in an attempt to get the value in a more direct way (I think)

```
var groupCode = element(
    by.id('group-sendgrid-hidden-input')
).getAttribute('value');


// and then later I want to do this:
var sendgridData = {envelope: 'what', test: groupCode};
```

The problem is that no matter what I try the value of the groupCode data never seems to resolve to a string.

1. I'm not able to `console.log(groupCode);`
2. This fails: `var sendgridDataString = JSON.stringify(sendgridData);`

Every time I get something like this:

```
{ ptor_: 
    { controlFlow: [Function],
      schedule: [Function],
      getSession: [Function],
      getCapabilities: [Function],
      quit: [Function],
      actions: [Function],....
```

And I'm sure the data I need is here, I'm just too new to protractor to figure it out. It is dope tech, however. Thank you.

#### Edit:

I have now also tried:

```
var groupCode = element(by.id('group-sendgrid-hidden-input')).evaluate('groupCode').then(function(groupCode){

        console.log('test: ' + groupCode);
        return value;
});
```

as well as :

```
var groupCode = element(by.id('group-sendgrid-hidden-input')).getAttribute('value').then(function(groupCode){

        console.log('test: ' + value);

    return value;
});
```

And in this second one, groupCode returns:

```
{ then: [Function: then],
    cancel: [Function: cancel],
    isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

Is still seems impossible to just get a string like `groupCode = 'just some words'`. Which is what I need to hand to another function.

I know this must be possible, but it is driving me to maddness. I will continue to read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discuss this question further and answer the original question here at this other question I asked about implementing the solution listed here, which is almost complete and finished with an expect condition that I have to write inside the `it` test.

[Cannot return string from value of element in protractor test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396338/cannot-return-string-from-value-of-element-in-protractor-test)

Answer (score 2):

`getAttribute()` as many other protractor methods *returns a promise*, you need to *resolve* it:

```
element(by.id('group-sendgrid-hidden-input')).getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Here are the relevant pages that should help to understand the concept of promises:

- [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow)
- [Protractor: How do promises work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570642/protractor-how-do-promises-work)
- [Asynchronous Testing with Protractor’s ControlFlow](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/)
- [Julie Ralph End to End Angular Testing with Protractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQipuiTcn3U) (great intro to protractor, in general)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I reviewed these docs. I can't see why `console.log(value);` is returning null (or possibly undefined). I will keep reading. Is there a function call I am missing?

Comment: @usumoio the key trick here is to use `then()` function to get an actual promise value once it's resolved. Hope it makes sense.